# Solving for $z$: $\frac{z}{1-z}=1-5i$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following equation for the complex number $z$:
$$
\frac{z}{1-z}=1-5i
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So we have $$\frac{z}{1 - z} = 1 - 5i$$

Now, assuming $z \neq 1$, (since otherwise we would have an undefined expression on the left hand side of the equation), we can multiply both sides of the equation by $1 - z$ to get:

$$(1-z)\frac{z}{(1 - z)} = (1 - z)(1 - 5i)$$

$$z = (1 - z)(1 - 5i)$$

Now, we can distribute the $1 - 5i$ across $(1 - z)$, and get:

$$z = 1(1 - 5i) - z(1 - 5i)$$

Then, we can add $z(1 - 5i)$ to both sides of the equation:

$$z + z(1 - 5i) = 1(1 - 5i) - z(1 - 5i) + z(1 - 5i)$$

$$z + z(1 - 5i) = 1(1 - 5i)$$

Now, we can factor out the common $z$ from the terms in the expression on the left hand side to get:

$$z(1 + (1 - 5i)) = 1(1 - 5i)$$

But addition is associative, so we can get rid of the parantheses in $1 + (1 - 5i)$ to get $1 + 1 - 5i = 2 - 5i$.  So we get:

$$z(2 - 5i) = 1 - 5i$$

Then, finally, dividing both sides by $2 - 5i$ gives:

$$\frac{z(2 - 5i)}{2 - 5i} = \frac{1 - 5i}{2 - 5i}$$

$$z = \frac{1 - 5i}{2 - 5i}$$.

Answer (score 6):

Isolate $z$ as you would isolate any variable (keeping in mind that $z\neq 1$):

$$\begin{align} \frac{z}{1-z}=1-5i &\iff z = (1 -5i)(1-z) \\ \\&\iff z+ (1-5i)z= 1-5i\\ \\ 
&\iff z(1+1-5i) = 1-5i \\ \\ &\iff z = \frac {1-5i}{2-5i}\end{align}$$

Now simplify (multiply the denominator by $2+5i$.)

$$\begin{align}  &\iff z = \frac {1-5i}{2-5i}\cdot\frac{2+5i}{2+5i} = \frac{(1-5i)(2+5i)}{4+25} \\ \\ 
\end{align}$$

Expand the numerator, simplify: $$\begin{align}  &\iff z= \frac{(1-5i)(2+5i)}{4+25} = \frac{2+5i - 10i + 25}{29}\\ \\ 
&\iff z = \frac{27-5i}{29}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply on both sides with $1-z$ to get $z = 1-5i+(1-5i)z$. Subtract $z-5iz$ and divide by $5i$ (note that $\frac{1}{i}=-i$).